# Filter exact date/time in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to filter out a record based on update time in Postgresql. My table, under update_timestamp field is storing the following dates:

```
update_timestamp
April 19, 2022, 7:03 PM
April 19, 2022, 7:01 PM
```

The timestamp for the second row is 2022-04-19 19:01:11:

```
SELECT to_char(update_timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
from my_table

to_char
2022-04-19 19:03:44
2022-04-19 19:01:11
```

Then, if I want to query the second date and time, I am converting string to timestamp:

```
select update_timestamp
from my_table 
where update_timestamp = to_timestamp('2022-04-19 19:01:11','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

As alternative, I can try another syntax:

```
select update_timestamp
from my_table 
where update_timestamp = '2022-04-19 19:01:11'::timestamp
```

What is the proper way to query date/time when passing a string? Am I doing something wrong?

Why a query such as this one is giving me the row I need (2022-04-19 19:01:11):

```
select update_timestamp
from my_table
where update_timestamp < '2022-04-19 19:03:00'
```

However, a query including the specific value as the following does not return any value:

```
select update_timestamp
from my_table
where update_timestamp = '2022-04-19 19:01:11'
```

Is the postgresql engine just able to query date ranges? This is working fine to get `2022-04-19 19:01:11`:

```
select update_timestamp
from my_table
where update_timestamp > '2022-04-19 19:01:10' and update_timestamp < '2022-04-19 19:01:12'
```

Thanks

Comment: Additional hint: You should really design your system infornt of the DB to deliver unified formatted date-types. That yould be the common way and minimize the time and logic inside the DB at all.

Comment: can you post also your `SHOW DateStyle` output?

Comment: Thanks @richyen, the value for `show datestyle` is: ISO, MDY

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74114112/trying-to-compare-timestamp-value-data/74114834#74114834

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a specific value of timestamp you should use date_trunc function, since timestamp has precision of microseconds

so for your example should be:

```
select update_timestamp
from my_table
where date_trunc('second',update_timestamp) = '2022-04-19 19:01:11';
```